# Spark Scala script Execution Command

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am New for the spark i have the Spark script like this

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

 /**

 * Loading sales csv using DataFrame API

 */

  object CsvDataInput {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {


   val sc = new SparkContext(args(0), "Csv loading example")
   val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc) 
   val df = sqlContext.load("com.databricks.spark.csv", Map("path" -> args(1),"header"->"true"))

   df.printSchema()
   df.registerTempTable("sales")

   val aggDF = sqlContext.sql("select sum(amt),code from sales where tran='CHG' group by amt,code")

    println(aggDF.collectAsList())  
   }

 }
```

How Can I execute that program in cloudera 
What command I have to use

I used this command

> ./bin/spark-shell --class classname --master local "Scriptpath" inputpath

but I am not getting output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spark-submit.  e.g.

```
./bin/spark-submit --class classname --master local[*] "Scriptpath" inputpath
```

Comment: Thans when I executed this program, I got the error like Class not fount execption what I have to do where was I missed

Comment: "inputpath" from your example needs to specify the jar file name.  The class name must include the package prefix.  Run "jar tf your.jar" to make sure your class is actually in your jar.

Comment: But I want to Execute the Script not jar.
Also When How to create jar when I am Copying this program I am getting error because of this is an Scala program.
So How to create jar file

Comment: Can't you just do "sbt run" then?

Comment: Get started with the simple build tool - http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Setup.html